# Pygame in-memory wave playback

Tags: python, pygame, wave

I'm generating waves with the Python Wave library, and using a custom file writer to store them in memory. However whenever I try to play them with Pygame, the playback is extremly slow. If I save the *exact same* object into a file, and then play it back, pygame plays it at normal speed.

The (someone abbreviated) code:

```
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init(size=8, buffer=2048, frequency=44100) #Thats the correct freq, but it does the same regardless
x = pygame.mixer.Sound(obj) #Load the output of the wave writer
x.play()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

With the details you have provided, my best guess is that you have not specified all of the parameters to pygame.mixer.init(), or have specified some incorrectly. Your comment insists that the frequency is correct, but that's not the only factor here. The size (8 bits, unsigned) is a factor, as are the channels (which are not mentioned in your code but default to 2 according to the Pygame docs).

When you created the wave, wrote it to a file, and then asked Pygame to play that wave file, all the necessary parameters were defined by the wave header.

So, double-check the bit width (size parameter), specify the channels parameter, and if that doesn't solve the problem, edit the original question to specify the code you used to write the wave file.